# I got this error when I add a background-image in a vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, sass, scss-mixins

I got this error when I added a background-image in a vue.js project:

**./src/assets/scss/argon.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-3-3!./src/assets/scss/argon.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../public/img/theme/home.jpg' in 'D:\work\Aliens\Front\src\assets\scss'**

I tried this command but no difference:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
'../../../../public/img/theme/home.jpg'
```

Try to use

```
'/img/theme/home.jpg'
```

on your `argon.scss` file.